# Spring Boot serialize parameteried type into JSON with type id

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson

Spring Boot sample project: 
https://github.com/yejianfengblue/spring-boot-jackson-serialize-generic-type

I have question in how Spring Boot serializes generic type into JSON with Jackson library. Please see my demo:

`Fruit` is a common interface of `Apple` and `Banana`.

`BasketController` has 3 RESTful API:

1. `getFruitList()` returns a `List<Fruit>`
2. `getFruitBasket()` returns a `FruitBasket`, which is a wrapper containing `List<Fruit>`
3. `getBasketOfFruit()` returns a `Basket<Fruit>`, which is a wrapper containing `List<T>`

In `BasketController`, I log the JSON string written from Jackson Object**Mapper** and Object**Writer**. Please see the actual output in the comment below the log statement.

**BasketController.java**

```
/** <li>Object<b>Mapper</b>.writeValueAsString, @type is lost due to java type erasure.
 *  <li>Object<b>Writer</b>.writeValueAsString, @type is kept */
@GetMapping(path = "getFruitList")
public List<Fruit> getFruitList() throws JsonProcessingException {

    List<Fruit> fruitList = Arrays.asList(new Apple(1), new Banana(2));
    log.info("List<Fruit> mapper.writeValueAsString: {}", mapper.writeValueAsString(fruitList));
    // log: List<Fruit> mapper.writeValueAsString: [{"wgt":1},{"wgt":2}]
    ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writerFor(new TypeReference<List<Fruit>>() {});
    log.info("List<Fruit> writer.writeValueAsString: {}", writer.writeValueAsString(fruitList));
    // log: List<Fruit> writer.writeValueAsString: [{"@type":"Apple","wgt":1},{"@type":"Banana","wgt":2}]
    return fruitList;
}

/** Object<b>Mapper</b>.writeValueAsString, with a wrapper of {@code List<Fruit>}, @type is kept */
@GetMapping(path = "getFruitBasket")
public FruitBasket getFruitBasket() throws JsonProcessingException {

    FruitBasket fruitBasket = new FruitBasket();
    fruitBasket.getItems().add(new Apple(3));
    fruitBasket.getItems().add(new Banana(4));
    log.info("FruitBasket mapper.writeValueAsString: {}", mapper.writeValueAsString(fruitBasket));
    // log: FruitBasket mapper.writeValueAsString: {"items":[{"@type":"Apple","wgt":3},{"@type":"Banana","wgt":4}]}
    return fruitBasket;
}

/** <li>Object<b>Mapper</b>.writeValueAsString, @type is lost due to java type erasure.
 *  <li>Object<b>Writer</b>.writeValueAsString, @type is kept */
@GetMapping(path = "getBasketOfFruit")
public Basket<Fruit> getBasketOfFruit() throws JsonProcessingException {

    Basket<Fruit> basketOfFruit = new Basket<Fruit>();
    basketOfFruit.getItems().add(new Apple(5));
    basketOfFruit.getItems().add(new Banana(6));
    log.info("Basket<Fruit> mapper.writeValueAsString: {}", mapper.writeValueAsString(basketOfFruit));
    // log: Basket<Fruit> mapper.writeValueAsString: {"items":[{"wgt":5},{"wgt":6}]}
    ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writerFor(new TypeReference<Basket<Fruit>>() {});
    log.info("Basket<Fruit> writer.writeValueAsString: {}", writer.writeValueAsString(basketOfFruit));
    // log: Basket<Fruit> writer.writeValueAsString: {"items":[{"@type":"Apple","wgt":5},{"@type":"Banana","wgt":6}]}
    return basketOfFruit;
}
```

I know Java type erasure that `List<Fruit>` is treated as `List<?>` in run-time.

`SpringBootBlueApplicationTests` tests the 3 RESTful API in order, and prints the JSON string serialized by Spring Boot:

1. `testGetFruitList()`: same JSON string with @type, as written by Object**Writer**.
2. `testGetFruitBasket()`: same JSON string with @type, as written by Object**Mapper**.
3. `testGetBasketOfFruit()`: same JSON string **without** @type, as written by Object**Mapper**.

**SpringBootBlueApplicationTests.java**

```
@Autowired
private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

/** Same json string as Object<b>Writer</b> writes with @type in BasketController.getFruitList() */
@Test
public void testGetFruitList() {

    log.info("/getFruitList JSON: {}", restTemplate.getForObject("/getFruitList", String.class));
    // log: /getFruitList JSON: [{"@type":"Apple","wgt":1},{"@type":"Banana","wgt":2}]
}

/** Same json string as Object<b>Mapper</b> writes with @type in BasketController.getFruitBasket() */
@Test
public void testGetFruitBasket() {

    log.info("/getFruitBasket JSON: {}", restTemplate.getForObject("/getFruitBasket", String.class));
    // log: /getFruitBasket JSON: {"items":[{"@type":"Apple","wgt":3},{"@type":"Banana","wgt":4}]}
}

/** Same json string as Object<b>Mapper</b> writes without @type in BasketController.getBasketOfFruit().
 * What I want is the string as Object<b>Writer</b> writes with @type */
@Test
public void testGetBasketOfFruit() {

    log.info("/getBasketOfFruit JSON: {}", restTemplate.getForObject("/getBasketOfFruit", String.class));
    // log: /getBasketOfFruit JSON: {"items":[{"wgt":5},{"wgt":6}]}
}
```

During JSON serialization in RESTful API 1 `getFruitList()`, Spring Boot knows the actual runtime type `Fruit` of `List<Fruit>`.

**Question:**

How can I make Spring Boot serializes `Basket<Fruit>` in RESTful API 3 `getBasketOfFruit`, so that it contains @type?

I find a reference about Custom JSON Serializers and Deserializers in https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-json-components.
But I have no clue in how to write the override method `serialize()`.

**Preliminary Solution**

Branch prelim_solution_with_jsonserializer https://github.com/yejianfengblue/spring-boot-jackson-serialize-generic-type/tree/prelim_solution_with_jsonserializer

I register 2 JsonSerializers and now `Basket<Fruit>` can be serialized with @type, but I don't know whether it's the best way to do it.

**BasketJsonSerializer.java**

```
@JsonComponent
public class BasketJsonSerializer {   

    public static class Serializer extends JsonSerializer<Basket<Fruit>> {    
        @Override
        public void serialize(Basket<Fruit> value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
                throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            gen.writeStartObject();
            gen.writeObjectField("items", value.getItems());
            gen.writeEndObject();
        }
    }
}
```

**FruitListJsonSerializer.java**

```
@JsonComponent
public class FruitListJsonSerializer {

    public static class Serializer extends JsonSerializer<List<Fruit>> {
        @Override
        public void serialize(List<Fruit> list, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
                throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            gen.writeStartArray();
            for (Fruit fruit : list)
                gen.writeObject(fruit);
            gen.writeEndArray();
        }
    }
}
```